# Issue reading Portuguese text file with "ê : você" character in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, exec, shell-exec

I have a text file in Portuguese that I created using PHP, which contains sentences with the character "ê" (e with circumflex accent). I'm trying to read this file in Python, but I'm encountering issues specifically with the "ê" character. I have ensured that both the PHP file and Python script are using the UTF-8 encoding.

Python script work fine in terminal but when I call this python file from php exec() or shell_exec() function python could not read text file content properly and print this error:

`'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`

What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

I have already tried the following steps:

1. Saving the PHP file with UTF-8 encoding.
2. Specifying the UTF-8 encoding explicitly when opening the file in Python.
3. Verifying that the default encoding in Python is set to UTF-8.

operating system: Linux

Python default encoding: utf-8

text file content:

`Se você tem 1 laranja e 1 limão faça esse delicioso bolo!`

Python code:

```
filename = "newfile.txt"
with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
 # Read the first line of the text file
 file_content = file.readline().strip()
 print(file_content)
```

terminal print:

[image: terminal side print work]

php file code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>read python</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$pythonScript = "read.py";
$command = "python3 " . $pythonScript;
$output = shell_exec($command); 
echo $output; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to handle this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the text file and the code you used?

Comment: Please add the contents and code to your original question

Comment: Please  @ShadowCrafter_01 check the code and content of file.

Comment: What is the result of `print(ascii(file_content))`?

Comment: python2.7 or python 3? Please be careful on the tags. it will help us to answer better (and not to lose time). I see python2.7 so for now I'm ignoring the question. (and for such question, it matter the version: there were a big change in this field)

Comment: @MarkTolonen the result of print(ascii(file_content)) is: '\ufeffSe voc\xea tem 1 laranja e 1 lim\xe3o fa\xe7a esse delicioso bolo!'

Comment: sorry @GiacomoCatenazzi about tags, this is for python 3 I have updated post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share output from `print(file_content)`. Your *"ê" character is not recognized properly* statement is too vague… Try `open(filename, "r", encoding="utf_8_sig")` as well.

Comment: What do you get from the `print` then? Are you on Windows? What is your output encoding?

Comment: @JosefZ thanks for your response, after using encoding="utf_8_sig" got this error: "'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
"

Comment: Hi @tripleee, I print text data from text  file in python by using in php's function exec() or shell_exec()

Comment: `print` function in Python depends on locale/culture of the process. What it seems, your webbrowser or you user do not have a UTF-8 locale as default. In general it doesn't matter much, because we do no print from webserver. (save to a file, e.g. a log file, so you can specify an encoding, and you can debug better the encoding/output problems). Using `sys.stdout.write` is also an option (and you cna specify the encoding)

Comment: I don't have the means to test this, but it seems to me that the simple fix would be to force Python to use UTF-8 with `PYTHONIOENCODING`

Comment: The initial `\ufeff` in the ASCII string is the byte order mark (BOM) character sometimes used as a signature for a UTF-8 file.  Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to remove that.  The rest of the string is correct so the problem is the encoding of the display, not Python.  If your terminal isn't configured for UTF-8 it will mis-decode the result.  On Windows with Python 3.11 in the command prompt a string with that content prints correctly: `Se você tem 1 laranja e 1 limão faça esse delicioso bolo!`.

Comment: if I run python on terminal that work fine , but if I call python from php file by using exec() or shell_exec() python can not read the text file, I have undated post with php code and terminal image please check the post again to better understand

Comment: Your PHP code does not seem to attempt to set `PYTHONIOENCODING`

Comment: @MarkTolonen you are right, terminal was not configured for UTF-8, I set local utf-8 in terminal before using exec() function in php 
` $locale='pt_BR.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
echo exec('locale charmap');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The initial `\ufeff` in the ASCII string is the byte order mark (BOM) character sometimes used as a signature for a UTF-8 file. Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to remove that. The rest of the string is correct so the problem is the encoding of the display, not Python. If your terminal isn't configured for UTF-8 it will mis-decode the result. On Windows with Python 3.11 in the command prompt a string with that content prints correctly: Se você tem 1 laranja e 1 limão faça esse delicioso bolo!.

@MarkTolonen is right, terminal was not configured for UTF-8, I set local utf-8 in terminal before using exec() function in php, now that is working.

PHP code:

```
$locale='pt_BR.UTF-8'; 
setlocale(LC_ALL,$locale); 
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```